# MySQL vs. MariaDB "A computed column cannot be based on a computed column"

Tags: mysql, mariadb

i have created a database in MySQL8 and there i have already a working tabel where one generated column is made out of date from another gernerated column...

than i made a webserver on a Raspberry Pi4 and there only MariaDB is availabel... fine i will just port the data and than i got an error that `#1900 - A computed column cannot be based on a computed column`

i am not sure why and i would need a workaround or is it just a ruleset which can be turned on...

if some additional data is required i will post it but i am not quite sure what would help...

and for disclaimer i am just starting whit the whole SQL, php, and web stuff ^^

Comment: if column a is say 2 * column b, and column c is say 3 * column a, then please change to column c = 6 * column b. (mathematically you can use the original column to do further computation)

Comment: My first column is fuel_added : `(´payed´ / ´price_per_liter´)` and the column which causes the error is fuel_level_before : `((((96 * (´fuel_level_after´ / 100)) - ´fuel_added´) / 96) * 100)`

Comment: then simply change the new column to ((((96 * (fuel_level_after / 100)) - (payed / price_per_liter)) / 96) * 100)

Comment: ahhh now i see... but when you work on a big database and have lot of generated columns this can get pretty long if you have to make such long expresions... and in my old database it worked flawless... is this a mariaDB specific "problem" or is it going to be fixed in a future update?

and thanks for the solution ^^

Comment: It requires at least MariaDB 10.2.1.